# Redirect after submit success redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I would like to ask if this is the proper way to redirect to another page after redux-form submit success:

```
const form = reduxForm({
    form: 'HeroesCreateComponentForm',
    validate,
    onSubmitSuccess: () => {
        console.log('onSubmitSuccess called (yes, yes I do get called');
        browserHistory.push('/')
    },
});
```

Comment: Yes, totally valid.

Comment: Hello! Im trying to do the same thing. How did you access your browserHistory in your onSubmitSuccess function? Did you pass it as a prop?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using next approach?

[react-router-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#what-if-i-want-to-issue-navigation-events-via-redux-actions)

```
import {push} from 'react-router-redux';
```

*onSubmitSuccess* has dispatch function as second parameter.
See [Redux form. onSubmitSuccess](https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-onsubmitsuccess-function-code-optional-)

```
onSubmitSuccess : (result,dispatch) =>{

dispatch(push('/needed-route'))

}
```